# ¿Cómo puedo crear un navegador basado en Chrome y no en Chromium?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, google-chrome, navegador-web

Estoy desarrollando un navegador con C#, por ahora va, aunque con algun pequeño problema; Pero se basa en Chromium, y quisiera que se base en Chrome, pues tengo entendido que Chromium es como beta (versión para desarrolladores del propio Chrome), y Chrome es la versión actual estable, y adecuada para un uso confiable.

Actualmente, estoy usando el NuGet CefSharp.WinForms; Creo que, necesitaría usar un recurso, que me ofrezca un control browser Chrome, pero no he encontrado nada en internet, que no sea lo que ya estoy usando (CefSharp.WinForms y ChromiumWebBrowser).

Gracias, Buen día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pides no es posible actualmente, al menos no de manera sencilla. Además no es necesario.

Chromium no es una BETA, es el proyecto base (de codigo abierto) sobre el que despues Google, añadiendo sus plugins y otros cambios, convierte en Chrome.

Es decir, Chrome es Chromium, solo que con los retoques de Google.

Puedes conocer más al respecto en https://www.genbeta.com/navegadores/cuales-son-las-diferencias-entre-chromium-y-google-chrome